# $this in php is bound dynamically, right?

Tags: php, dynamic, static, this

I'm getting an error that I *think* is because I've made some kind of mistake in a refactoring, but I can't find documentation on when `$this` is bound, and my error could be explained by it being bound statically.

Extra points (I can't actually give you extra points) for links to excellent documentation about this kind of thing in php.

[Edit]
The error that I'm getting is telling me that `Subclass::$var` doesn't exist when I do, for example, `echo $this->var` in a superclass. The `$var` exists in the subclass, though.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate more on the error and show the code you think may be wrong.

Comment: More details, please. `$this` is available within object from the beginning of the contructor till the end. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in PHP:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo $this->bar;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public $bar = 1;
}

$b = new B;
$b->foo();  // 1
```

It works because of the dynamic scope resolution that PHP has (i.e.: scope is resolved at runtime as opposed to compile time). However, I'd recommend against it, because it is really a particularity of the language for one. For second, failing to declare `$bar` in a subclass would result in an error. I think that a class should only reference members that it is aware of.

The same code, say in C++:

```
class A {

public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << bar;
    }

};

class B : public A {

public:
    int bar;
    B() {
        bar = 1;
    }

};
```

...would give you a compile error (*In A::foo(): 'bar' was not declared in this scope*).

Comment: You're right, really what I want is `abstract protected $bar` in the base class (A) for clarity. Of course, php only has abstract methods, not properties, so I can't really do that "correctly", but a comment is nearly as good as a compiler exception.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` becomes available after you've called the constructor. Logically you can't use `$this` in a `static` function.

Aside from calling `$this` in a `static` function there isn't a whole lot that can go wrong timing wise as there is simply no way in PHP.

What exactly is the error you're getting? Code would useful too.

Comment: +1 It is available from the beginning of the constructor until the destruction of the object. OP is probably trying to call `$this` from the static method, as you thought.

Comment: I added some details, it's not a `static` issue here. I'm using it in various ways in sub- and superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$this` is bound dynamically, as is evidenced by the fact that the output of the following is "foo":

```
<?php
class Base
{
    public function ecc(){
        echo $this->subvar;
    }
}

class Sub extends Base
{
    public $subvar;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->subvar = 'foo';
        $this->ecc();
    }
}
new Sub();
?>
```