# Parent static function calling static child variable

Tags: php, visibility, php-5.2, late-static-binding

Here's a simplfied version of the classes I'm dealing with

```
class A {
   static protected function getVal() {
              return self::$valB;
            }
}
class B extend A {
   static protected $valB = 'Hello';
}
B::getVal(); // Hello
```

Should this work in php version 5.2.17 or do I have it setup wrong. I'm currently getting an error saying that it can't find `A::$valB`.

Comment: Actual error "Access to undeclared static property: A::$valB"

Answer (score 3):

Requires late static binding, which is present in PHP 5.3.0 and later.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

In getVal, you'd want to use `return static::valB;` instead of `return self::valB;`

Answer (score 1):

First, your code syntax is wrong. Start by fixing it:

```
class A {
   static protected function getVal() {
       return self::$valB;
   }
}
class B extends A {
   static protected $valB = 'Hello';
}
B::getVal();
```

Now, this will never work because `getVal` is protected. Unless you call it from `A` or one of its child, it won't work.

The `self` keyword resolves to the class that calls it. Since `self` is used in `A`: `self == A`.

You will need to use late static bindings to fix it:

```
return static::$valB;
```

Lastly, I'd recommend you also declare `$valB` in `A` to avoid fatal errors:

```
class A {
    static protected $valB;
    static protected function getVal() { ... }
}
```

Comment: The reason for $valB being declared in B is because there will be a B.C. D, E classes that will extend A that will all have different values for $valB. The static call works like a charm but in production only PHP v5.2 is available. Maybe this should have been the question in the first place.

Comment: @Clutch: Yes, I figured you'd implement `$valB` in sub-classes, but keep in mind that this is a "language feature", other languages will not allow this (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165135/this-in-php-is-bound-dynamically-right/6165380#6165380)). As for 5.2, there is a no workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: @Clutch You should try convincing either your employer or client to update to PHP 5.3, here's some ammo: PHP 5.2 is unsupported now by Zend and no longer provided with security patches. :)